# Происхождение слова "пупок"

Tags: этимология

Может кто-нибудь рассказать о происхождении слова "пупок"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово *пупок* 'круглый рубец на середине живота' образовано прибавлением суффикса *-ок*, имеющего уменьшительное значение, к существительному *пуп* 'то же'.

Слово *пуп*, в свою очередь, является общеславянским (ср. др.-рус. *пупъ*, болг. *пъп*, чешск. *pupek*) и восходит к существительному **ро̨ръ*.

Само же существительное *пупок* встречается уже в древнерусских текстах (*пупокъ*) и, скорее всего, восходит к аналогичному общеславянскому производному.

Таким образом, это исконно русское слово. Такие слова, как, например, пуповина и пупырь 'прыщ', – его исторические «родственники».

*Использовались данные «Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов» под ред. Н. Ю. Шведовой.*

Answer (score 2):

**Пупок**, также пуп.

Др.-рус. (с XI века) ― **пупъ**, **пупокъ.**

Общеславянский корень **popъ**. Возможно, старшее значение на слав. почве ― почка.

Лат. **pumpinos** ― виноградный побег, в греческом языке похожее слово обозначает "водяной пузырь".

И.-е. корень **pump** ― нечто набухшее, глаголы *пухнуть, набухать*.

Материал взят из словаря Черных.

Comment: Jasmin, вы забыли указать на то, что праславянские и и.-е. слова реконструированы.

Comment: Я использовала слово "корень", чтобы не рассказывать о реконструированных языках (это не тема вопроса).  Но тогда уж  и Вы скажите, правильно ли говорить "является общеславянским ...и восходит к праславянскому..."? Ведь, кажется. праславянский и общеславянский язык - это одно и тоже? И насчет исконности слова тоже есть вопрос. Исконными вроде бы являются слова, образованные в русском языке с 14 века, а слово пупокъ Черных относит к др.-рус. языку.

Comment: Jasmin, во-первых, любая морфема или лексема, связанная с праславянским (общеславянским), реконструирована и должна быть снабжена значком * (мое замечание касается именно этого). Во-вторых, почитать о том, что в лексикологии называется *исконно русскими словами*, можно, например, [здесь](http://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/6-klass/leksika-frazeologiia-leksikografiia-15751/iskonno-russkie-i-zaimstvovannye-slova-10520/re-a518df81-a401-4de0-bb9b-9522811fe4fa), хотя, как по мне, есть тексты получше.

Comment: Так-то оно так,  да только в качестве вывода смотрится странно. Наверное, в этих случаях надо говорить "общеславянская исконная лексика", чтобы хотя бы как-то сообщить нужную информацию. А когда говорят просто "исконно русская лексика" в общем понимании, то неясно, в какой исторический период образовалось слово. Вы в ответе об общеславянском происхождении говорите, а корень-то его постарше будет. И что тогда означает Ваш вывод? Что корень только общеславянский, а это сомнительно. Поэтому я бы с осторожностью называла  все слова с и.-е.  корнями исконно русскими, хотя это и общепринятый термин.

Comment: непонятно, в чем вы видите недочет: исконно русская лексика в некоторых случаях может быть возведена к ностратическим основам — и, собственно, что?

Comment: Да при чем тут это, недочет в неясности информации. Исконно русская лексика - это всё, что не было заимствовано из других языков после 14 века.  А вот интересно, в какой период был добавлен суффикс ОК. У Черных это слово было в др.-рус. языке, а у Вас - неизвестно когда, "исконно русское" такой информации не дает, а косвенно может намекать и на  недавнее словообразование.

Comment: по вашему определению слово «хлеб» исконно русское, так что советую его [определение] подкорректировать. Ну, у вас тоже не особо понятно, когда был добавлен суффикс. Я привожу синхронное рассмотрение морфемного состава, а этимологически анализирую слово «пуп». Я постараюсь добавить хронологические сведения, если угодно.

Comment: Да пожалуйста, очень даже угодно, добавляйте. Всё, что связано с конкретной историей слов, всегда очень интересно, и даже прежде всего интересно. Про суффикс я уже сказала - он был уже в др.-рус. слове пупокъ. Спасибо за участие в диалоге: никто к разговору не присоединяется, а система недовольна.

Comment: Аналогичная формулировка: суффикс ОК был уже в среднерусском слове пупокъ (и что? ну да, старенькое слово) — вы не уточняете, когда суффикс был добавлен, чего требуете от меня...

Answer (score -2):

[корень П][1]
http://www.proza.ru/2018/02/23/2179

[1]: http://www.proza.ru/pics/2018/02/23/2179.jpg?8619   > > > ...
Пуп = Пой-Пой = изобилие изобилия... = средоточие изобилия качеств (энергий).

Poop (англ.) – верхняя площадка-крыша на палубе корабля, особенно на парусном судне, где он обычно образует крышу каюты на корме. Черпнуть кормой. Экскременты, дефекации.

Pupo – красотка, малютка babe (англ)
Puppa – болван boob (англ), гудок сирена
Pup; - bullshit shit
Puppola - удод
Слова с двойной П могут особенно (удвоение = усиление) показывать смыслы звука П.
Какой человек самый большой и великий (супер изобилующий качествами - самый сильный и великий)? -  Это Папа - по меньшей мере это справедливо для детей из нормальных семей и для католиков; а для православных - главный Поп.
Кстати, Попа (часть тела)  - тоже (в идеале) стремится к совершенной полноте.
Pep (англ.) - бодрость, энергия.
Санскритское Паапа - беда зло; это и понятно - ведь полная полнота (П*П) это уже есть переизбыток - т. е. когда что то сверх меры (беспредел), отсюда и санскритское Упапаата - беда катастрофа. 
И заметьте в санскритском уПаПааТа тот же набор (П*П*Т) что и в русском ПоТоП, и тот же смысл - Беда-Катастрофа. 
В греческом тоже есть слово "Потоп" - Potapos), Potapi - презренный несчастный; 
Видимо у древних греков это было нормальным названием для пережившего потоп (наводнение), как и позже для погорельца (потопленца). И возможно у шумеров такое сочетание корней ППТ тоже дало значение «ПоТоП», близкое к др.греч. - Несчастный (который нуждается в помощи – автор) : TaPPuTu шумер – Помощь. Во многих современных словарных значениях шумерских слов нельзя быть вполне уверенными, возможно часто современные переводчики предлагают не самые близкие синонимы или вовсе ошибочные варианты…. Однако «Помощь (шумер Таппуту)» кажется вполне обоснованным :
Т*ПП* = Т-Полнота изобилия. Корень Т передаёт древнейшие значения (смотри «Звук Т») – Твердь, Сила, Основание-опора-поддержка-ПОМОЩЬ.

Примечательно - слово-понятие Потоп стало ключевым для прочтения Фестского диска. На диске это слово обозначено тремя знаками - два полных мешка и между ними знак Вода (волнистые линии); это сочетание знаков и передаёт смысл - "Полная воды Полнота" (переизбыток)  = ПотоП.
Санскритское Пета - много, мешок.
Natappu тамил. –процветание (изобилие – автор), поток, влияние, поведение, цель, место назначения, прохождение, преступная близость - как между мужчиной и женщиной.
...
...